How to click on a button with selenium. (Java, Selenium)
I'm trying to use Selenium to click a button that loads more news on the page, but I always end up facing an org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException or org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException. I feel like I'm lacking more knowledge about frontend, and I'm not sure if it's a problem in the code or a site protection mechanism. I have already managed to use Selenium to enter one of the news articles, but I can never scroll down to the button or identify it. Could someone help clarify my doubts?
The code:
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeD\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)); // Maximum wait time of 30 seconds
        wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
                ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
        // Locate the "Load more" button
        WebElement loadMoreButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'text-white') and contains(@class, 'bg-wl-neutral-950')]")));
        // Scroll to the button using JavaScript
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", loadMoreButton);
        loadMoreButton.click();
    }
}

I've tried scrolling and making various manipulations, such as forcing Selenium to wait a certain amount of time until the page loads, but no success.

get rid of readyState check and scroll... you don't need that.  Include your full exception.  It'll list the element that would receive the click.  (it's usually a prompt or a progress indicator that is on-top... you'd deal with that first.)  The click method is going to scroll the element into the visible viewport, check it's location, calculate the center of the element, then click in the center.  If the click would end up clicking another element first, it'll throw the click intercepted error.

also use the expected condition of elementToBeClickable instead of visibilityOf...  (that'll help in certain cases...)

It seems like the problem is the Webelement.
Can You try this:
WebElement loadMoreButton=(//button[@data-ds-variant='secondary'])[2] 

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", loadMoreButton);

loadMoreButton.click();

